# Does Emacs 23 support prog-mode-hook?

Tags: emacs

I want to add some common settings for the programming modes. such like: turn on watchwords, highlight parentheses, and so on.
so I add code as follow:

`(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'turn-on-watchwords)`

This works in Emacs 24, but Emacs 23 doesn't works, I don't know if is something else missing or Emacs 23 itself makes this doesn't work.

If Emacs 23 doesn't support prog-mode-hook, how can I add the common settings for programming mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`prog-mode` (and so all the hooks associated with it) was added in Emacs 24.

You can simulate it (slightly) by just adding your hook to all the programming hooks you normally use (admittedly this is a little bit hacky):

```
(mapc (lambda (mode-hook) (add-hook mode-hook 'turn-on-watchwords))
        '(c-mode-common-hook tcl-mode-hook emacs-lisp-mode-hook
          ruby-mode-hook java-mode-hook haskell-mode-hook
          ess-mode-hook python-mode-hook sh-mode-hook))
```

Comment: thanks, that works for me. But it seems to be a long hook list to make sure cover most programming modes.

Comment: @hbin, you only need to list the ones you normally use, that list above is the one in my `.emacs`, so if you don't use Ruby or Haskell (for example), you can remove it from the list. (Also, if this solves your problem, please click the outline of a checkmark next to the answer to mark it as "accepted" :) )

Answer (score 2):

No Emacs so far, 23 or 24 uses `prog-mode` consistently.  Emacs 24 has 51/85 files containing "prog-mode" in lisp/progmodes/*.el, to give you an idea of coverage.  Maybe in a future version you will be able to use `prog-mode-hook` like you want.

There is no way to add a hook to all "programming" modes.  @dbaupp's solution of keeping a list of hooks you use is the best solution available.